# How to call nested script in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have following script hierarchy.

```
Scripts/master.sql
Scripts/GB/gb.sql
Scripts/GB/user1/insert.sql
```

master.sql contains simple @script to call gb.sql
e.g.

```
@GB/gb.sql
```

gb.sql contains below

```
@user1/insert.sql
```

The problem is that if i run master.sql from Scripts directory, i get below error:

```
unable to find insert.sql
```

Whereas if I execute gb.sql from GB directory, ir run successfully. 
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL*Plus directories are always reletive to the original working directory.  Your scripts will need to repeat the full path from the working directory each time.

Change gb.sql to:

```
@GB/user1/insert.sql
```

The `@@` can be used to reference files in the same directory as the running file, but `@@` does not work with sub directories.